# Wavelet function: rewrite matlab wavelet code to R

Tags: r, matlab, wavelet

I am having matlab code:

```
wt = modwt(datavalue,'db1',7);
```

I want to conver this code to R, which I have done in following manner:

```
wt = modwt(datavalue,wf = 'db2',n.levels = 7)
```

But this keeps giving me error

```
Error in modwt(datavalue, wf = "db2", n.levels = 7) : 
  unused argument (wf = "db2")
```

Also if I write the code like this

```
wt = modwt(datavalue,'db2',7)
```

It gives me the following error

```
Error in wt.filter(filter, modwt = TRUE) : Invalid filter name.
```

I am using the wavelet function and probably I am not able to understand the wavelet function in R.
Is this the right of of transforming the code to R or is there any other package in R that would be better than wavelet package

Comment: Could you please provide a sample dataset and the package that you're using?

Comment: The datavalue is a 302537*1 dataframe something like this below.
84.33630371
99.51580048
103.2020034
74.68540192
133.9490051
93.40519714
70.85410309

Comment: @DJV I am using the wavelets package

Comment: If possible,  please use dput()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully familiar with the MATLAB function `modwt`. However, you can try the R package `waveslim`, and the function `modwt`.
It looks the same, see the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/waveslim/versions/1.12/topics/modwt).

```
require(waveslim)

data(ibm)     
ibm.returns <- diff(log(ibm))
ibmrWave <- modwt(ibm.returns, wf = "la8", n.levels = 4)
```

Comment: They have not listed the wavelet filters that can be used. By default they have mentioned wf = "la8".

I want db1 or db2 wavelet filter to be used. But when I am putting the same it gives error.

Is there any alternative to this in R?

Comment: In both packages waveslim and wavelets you can use only wt.filter filters. Use ?wt.filters to get the full list (The character strings currently supported are derived from one of four classes of wavelet transform filters: Daubechies, Least Asymetric, Best Localized and Coiflet).